# 24v 450w DC motor powered electric bike connected to a lith-ion battery pack (56v 6.5a)

Tags: motor, dc

How do I prevent the DC motor from burning out using this battery pack?

Comment: After connecting the battery pack to the electric bicycle, the response was spectacular. The throttle control mounted on the bike performed very well.  The bike actually achieved 40.1 mph on a dry somewhat flat road surface.  The wiring harness, controller and battery pack did not overheat, but the motor did become quite warm.  The motor is the traditional metal brush design.  I am very concerned that I will eventually destroy the motor and would appreciate some advice/guidance as to how I can prevent that.

Comment: Welcome to EESE! Might I suggest linking the specific motor you have.  Datasheets never hurt and are a great place for an potential answerer to look if some piece of information they need isn't properly clarified.

Comment: Why don't you put an ammeter in series with the motor? It really shouldn't be in any danger unless it goes above 20A or so.

Comment: Yes, I'll try that!  The ammeter would act as overload protection.  Very constructive advice.  Thank you!

Comment: OK, I've measured the current across the circuit using my ammeter.  As a result, I marked a "do not exceed" point on the throttle control that corresponds with 6 amperes to prevent an overdraw of current (>6.5amps) from the battery pack.  Seems to perform satisfactory.  The motor does not heat up as much and the bike retains most of the improved performance characteristics using the lithium-ion battery pack.  The overload solution is not fancy, but it's practical and serves the purposes intended.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If 6.5A is the max discharge rate of the pack then the motor can only have about 15A put into it. At 24V that is only 360W, so if it needs 450W to do what you want you will need a different pack.

Completely re-editing my answer after a string of useless comments.

Not knowing what controller you're using makes this impossible to answer. The only suggestion I can leave you with not knowing the controller is us a DCDC buck converter to go from Battery-pack to 24V then feed that into the controller. As far as I can tell the only thing you changed that made the motor run extra hot was the input voltage to the controller. It used to be 24V then you made it 56V. Without knowing any other information, keep the input voltage to 24V and it should run similar to before.

Another possibility though (and we can't know cause we have zero information about the motor also) is that it wants high current pulses and the battery pack can't do more than 6.5A. This would cause a rise in motor temperature. Good luck.

Comment: 6.5A  = 6.5 amperes (discharge limit of the battery pack)

Comment: The motor is rated at 24 volt 450 watts.  The original battery pack was a sealed lead acid (SLA) type rated at 24v - 10 amperes.

Comment: How are you driving it? What controller are you using? Can't help you anymore until I know this. I'm assuming PWM to drop down the 56V to 24V? But if you want variable speed then you'll need to vary that average voltage.

Comment: The motor is attached to the bicycle rear sprocket and is control by a twist throttle mounted on the handle bars and electronic controller mounted within in enclosure above the rear wheel.  I am not sure what your are asking "How is the motor being driven?"

Comment: What electronic controller are you using? Not knowing it's input requirements makes answering your original question impossible.

Comment: I am not sure.  Where would I find that information?  I did not see a decal for that or stamped on the controller enclosure.  I am assuming it's ratings parameters are equivalent to what the original supplied SLA battery pack (24v @ 10amps).  Input requirements appear to have no minimum in that the controller responds to almost full depletion of the SLA battery pack.

Comment: The rear wheels spin (albeit, very slowly) even when the SLA battery pack is very low.

Comment: No "di minimus" cut off from the controller has ever been observed.

Comment: My overall intention is to upgrade the electric bike's power source to lithium ion battery.

Comment: We can't infer if connecting 56V to this controller will cause poor operation just as well as you can't without knowing the controller specs.

Comment: Poor operation is not so much an issue.  When connected and the bike operated under load conditions (riding it), the bike ran flawlessly and faster.  No damage has been observed yet.  I am considering adding a thermal fuse rated at 9 amps that will at least cut power should the wiring begin to overheat, but I am not sure if that will also protect the motor in the long run.

Comment: Despite not knowing the controller's specs, the controller does not seem to be affected by the change in power source (no overheat and no excessive draw).  I think what I may need are some suggestions to construct a protective circuit to prevent overheating the motor.

Comment: This question is horrible and the comments worse. If the controller is doing its job why would you need to worry about the motor overheating?

Comment: Because it will.  When in operation, the motor has been observed to heat up more so then it did when it was powered using the SLA battery.  The lith-ion battery pack is supplying a higher voltage.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I cannot take measures to control the voltage and avoid overload damage with the approach I am taking?